# Autentificar (LOGIN) con Sistema de Seguridad de Google

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, oauth2

Desarrollo una aplicación ASP.NET WebForms y necesito que si el usuario se ha autenticado en el navegador con una cuenta Google  pueda acceder a la página de lo contrario no.

Comment: Hola Efrain, bienvenido a SOes, a lo que te refieres es al Login utilizando la cuenta de Google, podrías ser más específico? Qué estas utilizando? ASP.net WebForms? MVC 4? 5? 6? Te invito a leer http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a mejor redacción de preguntas, mejor redacción de respuestas. saludos

Comment: Imaginate que un usuario abrio su cuenta google en su navegador , entonces ya puede acceder al sitio de lo contrario no

Comment: así como el login de este sitio que te pide cuenta de Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public void GoogleAutentificacion()
    {
        GoogleConnect.ClientId = Valor.GoogleClientId ();
        GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = Valor.GoogleClientSecret ();
        GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
        {
            String code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            String json = GoogleConnect.Fetch("me", code);
            Controller.DataGoogle.GoogleProfile perfil = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Controller.DataGoogle.GoogleProfile>(json);
            Session["PerfilID"] = perfil.Id;
            Session["PerfilNombre"] = perfil.DisplayName;
            Session["PerfilEmail"] = perfil.Emails.Find(email => email.Type == "account").Value;
            Session["PerfilSexo"] = perfil.Gender;
            Session["PerfilTipo"] = perfil.ObjectType;
            Session["PerfilImagen"] = perfil.Image.Url.ToString();
        }
        if (Session["PerfilEmail"] != null) 
        {
            if (Sub.ValidarMail(Session["PerfilEmail"].ToString().ToLower()))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/View/StaGemaList/MenuPrincipal.aspx"); 
            }
            else 
            {
                String ScriptAct = "<script language='javascript'>" + "NoAutenticadoStaGema();" + "</script>";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "NoAutenticadoStaGema();", ScriptAct);
            }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar las credenciales de google en tu aplicacion, pero deberas implementar especificamente el login que solicite las credenciales, no existe ningun auto-login automatico.

Vas a tener que utilizar `OAuth`

[OAuth for ASP.NET  Google](http://www.oauthforaspnet.com/providers/google/)

[Google API Client Libraries OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)

como observaras requieres la llamada a una api que use un `Client ID` para autorizar la autenticacion y retorne un token que usaras en tu desarrollo

Puede que si otra aplicacion ya se haya autenticado previamente los datos de las credenciales esten persistidos y la nueva autenticacion sea algo directo, pero igualmente requieres implementar la infraestructura de OAuth y realizar la llamada.

Comment: Gracias Leandro ...Fino funciono perfecto ....y este este ejemplo esta muy bueno

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-with-Google-Account-API-in-ASPNet-and-get-Google-Plus-Profile-details.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Estrictamente Lo que pides no creo que se pueda hacer.

Google es bastante estricto con su política de seguridad así que no puedes pillar la autenticación de navegador sin más para usarla en tu aplicación. Eso te daría acceso , por ejemplo, a la dirección de correo del usuario cosa terminalmente prohibida por google. (contraejemplo, tu aplicación podría ser un capturador de emails sin que los usuarios lo supieran)

Lo que si que puedes hacer es logear en tu aplicación con la cuenta de google, pero el usuario deberá admitir los permisos estrictos de lo que estés usando en la aplicación.

Para ello deberás usar el protocolo OAuth 2.0 para logearte . Más información la tienes la página oficial de google : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth

Si tienes dudas sobre como usar OAuth deberás hacer una nueva pregunta ya que no tendrá nada que ver con esta.

Comment: Gracias ...me sirvio de muchooo...